# Load only required services spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I'm looking for a way to create a free version and a paid version of an application. I was wondering if spring has the functionality to group/tag services so I can switch between services i.e. services which don't do much for a free user and the actual service for the paid user.

Is this the right approach? or is there another framework which lets me do this and works well with spring?

Is there a way I can do the same in the front end i.e. show or hide features/icons based on the type of user?

-- Edited --

The project is a multi module maven project with a war module and 3 jars which uses Spring framework with spring security (nothing fancy) and angularjs.

The requirement is that I should be able to build the war file based on different configuration. For example, lets say a client doesn't want a particular feature, I should be able to  turn it off by just changing some configuration. So the user will not see that particular feature anymore.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to do the licensing in your code. Its much 
 more flexible, and its not difficult to implement! and easier to maintain....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bean definition profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-in-3.1-bean-definition-profiles) to use different bean implementations depending on startup parameters, but that would require that you are in charge of the startup parameters used for launching the application (i.e. this would not be a suitable solution for an application that is downloaded and run by the customer on his own machine; then the startup profile settings could be hacked).

More information on the intended application architecture is probably needed to give good advice here.

Comment: It sounds like you need to build completely different binaries for different clients, in which case you would need to use maven to get the correct stuff included. If you separate different implementations of your services into different maven modules you can use maven profiles in your war project to determine which sub-module to depend on for a specific build type.

Comment: I'm doing the same for now. I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Well, bean definition profiles would technically do what you want, which would enable you to turn on/off features using configuration/startup parameters, but as long as everything is actually included in the binary there's nothing to stop anyone that downloaded the binary from figuring out how to configure the system any way they want. If this is not a problem I would go with bean definition profiles; otherwise you'll need to just include the things they can use in the binary or devise some licensing scheme to prevent invalid configurations based on the presented license.